# In Javascript, what memory implications does passing around large objects as function arguments have?

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming

I just want to confirm if the following is true:

I know javascript function calls are "call by value" but when it comes to objects the "value" is a reference. Does this mean, hypothetically, if I constantly keep passing around an object that is... say 1MB, would this have no overhead memory management wise? (Since all this time it's just passing around a reference and not the 1MB value for every function call)

Comment: I'd say you're right, if you keep passing around the same object, it stays in the same place in memory, and wouldn't take up any more memory, other than the new references to that same object.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101

Comment: "By value" for references means "values of references". No new memory allocated for objects.

Comment: Another term in the context of objects is `call by sharing`, because you always pass around a copy of the reference (or address) of an object, not an alias.